# Are input type="button" elements readonly? Firefox seems to think so:

Tags: html, css, firefox, button

Given the html

```css
input {
  color: blue
}

input:read-only {
  color: red
}

input:-moz-read-only {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="normal">
<input type="button" value="normal">
<input type="text" readonly="true" value="readonly">
<input type="button" readonly value="readonly">
```

Firefox (77 and 78 i have tested) shows the elements as:

blue, red, red, red (not-readonly, readonly, readonly, readonly)

Chrome and edgium show:

blue, blue, red, blue (not, not, readonly, not).

Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly) say

> Note: Only text controls can be made read-only, since for other controls (such as checkboxes and buttons) there is no useful distinction between being read-only and being disabled, so the readonly attribute does not apply.

Yet, firefox clearly interprets all inputs with a type of button as being readonly (at least for the CSS).

Is this correct? Chrome acts as I would have expected firefox to based on the mozilla page - the readonly attribute, even if applied, is ignored.

I am having a css issue which I dare say I can fix by specifying types in the CSS, but I am not sure if this is a firefox bug, or quirk.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `<input type="button">` instead of `<button>`? The `<button>` element is superior in every way.

Comment: "I am not sure if this is a firefox bug, or quirk." - my money's on it being a quirk caused by the HTML+CSS specification being imprecise on this. That said, no-one should be using `<input type="button">` anyway, so I think it's a moot issue.

Comment: FWIW, Safari acts the same as Firefox…

Comment: Yes indeed - should of course be `<button>`- it is proprietary higher education software that we use which is generating the html. So I don't have (easy) control over the element itself.

Comment: Same result for `<input type="submit">` which is the correct element to use in a form.

Comment: @andy1749313 `<input type="submit">` is obviated by `<button type="submit">`. The only reason people were using `<input type="submit">` instead of `<button type="submit">` was due to a bug in IE6 (where it would incorrectly handle the `name` and `value` attributes on a `<button>`). IE6 is long irrelevant.

Comment: If you can inject your own JavaScript into the page, you could replace every `input[type=submit]` with `button[type=submit]`.

Answer (score 4):

The comments correctly pointed out that these elements are largely redundant now - however, as I said, I am not in control of the elements themselves.

So I could have used js to change the elements themselves, however, I thought that was perhaps a bit over the top. I have also had issues with that - accessibility validation tools (like total validator) will tend to read the original source, and can flag up errors on the initial rather than the unmodified code.

I just refined the css itself, from

```
input:read-only
```

to

```
input:read-only:not([type=button]):not([type=submit])
```

It still seems to me that this is slightly unusual behaviour from firefox, but perhaps it is just me.